# root@localhost とは何を表していますか？

Tags: プログラミング言語

突然出てきて、何なのかわかりません。プログラミング初心者なので、詳しいことではなく、わかり易く簡単に書いていただけると有り難いです。

Comment: 「突然出てきた」という状況はどんなものでしょう？ 例えば何処の書籍・資料の何ページ等の記述場所とか、何かの装置やソフトウェアを操作していて、こんな場合にこんな風に出てきたとか、詳細を記述してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事等を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 「ラインズeライブラリ」というアプリケーションのプログラム画面に間違えていったときに出てきました。プログラムの中にあったものです。

Comment: こちらのサイト [ラインズ｜ラインズ株式会社－eラーニングとICT支援サービス ...](https://www.education.jp/), [ラインズeライブラリアドバンス](https://katei.kodomo.ne.jp/pc/student/kateitop/login/) の関連でしょうか？ 有料かあるいは契約者のみアクセス可能なサイト/サービスのようですし、「突然出てきた」というより貴方が偶然入ってしまって表示された物のようですから、それが何かを特定したり情報を得るのは難しいでしょうね。該当のサービスを最初から受けていれば徐々に知識が増えて理解できるものである可能性があります。しかし偶然なら関係無いことはこだわらずに忘れた方が現在行っていると思われるプログラミング学習のためには良いと思われます。

Comment: アドバイス、ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

まあ普通には `root` というのはコンピュータの管理者で `localhost` ってのは今目の前にあるあなたのコンピュータのことです。アットマークはメールアドレスのアットマークと同じ。こういう組織（コンピュータ）がアットマークの右側、ユーザー名がアットマークの左側。

管理者権限でコンピュータを使うと誤操作１回で OS を/コンピュータそのものを壊すことができる関係で、普段常用する際には管理者権限なしなアカウントを使うことが推奨されますが、インストールだの設定変更だのをする際には管理者権限が必要なことも多々あります。

`root@localhost` というときは目の前のコンピュータを管理者権限で操作する、みたいな意味合いだと考えてくれればそんなに間違っていないでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。